# Trying to click on the 2nd element with the same class using Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I have been trying out a lot of different ways to click on a particular element on the browser using Nightwatch.js  (nth-child, nth-of-type, etc), and so far I am not able to find the correct element.  I am trying to click on the 2nd "More" button on the screen.

[image]

The HTML looks like this.  Both of the "More" buttons have the exact same class, and are nested within a div that has a key difference in the class, in that one is called discover-teams and the second is nested within a div that has a class of discover-athletes.  If I try something like this, I end up clicking on one of the follow buttons on the image

```
.click('.discover-athletes div:nth-child(3) button')
```

[image]

If anyone knows of the best way to do this I would greatly appreciate it.  So far I am coming up short.  Much obliged

Answer (score 1):

I see that the page has two ".discover-athletes" so the selector for 2nd button should be :

```
'test' : function(browser){
       const 2ndSelector = 'div[class="discover-athletes"]:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > button';
       browser.click(2ndSelector);
          }
```

You need symbol ">" to make selector more accurate.

Edit:there is only 1 ".discover-athletes",but it make no difference.

```
        'test' : function(browser){
           const 2ndSelector = 'div[class="discover-athletes"] > div:nth-child(3) > button';
           browser.waitForElementVisible(2ndSelector,5000,false,function(result){
                 browser.click(2ndSelector);
                          });              
                  }
```

Comment: I only see one ".discover-athletes".  There is a ".discover-teams" as well, but only one of each.

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of them.

```
browser.click('.discover-athletes.discover-card div:nth-child(3) button');
```

OR

```
browser.click('.discover-athletes.discover-card div:discover-card-load-more.discover-card-footer button');
```

OR

```
browser.click('.discover-athletes.discover-card div:discover-card-load-more button');
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution that worked.

```
.click('.discover-athletes .discover-card-load-more')
```

Just needed to keep digging a bit (this is my first time trying to search for elements in html using a testing framework).  But I appreciate the answer you both submitted.  Cheers

Comment: Do you know if this works at all with Nightwatch page objects?

Comment: I can't say for sure.  I haven't been using Nightwatch for a few months now since I was laid off from the company I was building the testing suite for.  Ultimately it boils down to the position of the element in the DOM, and specifically pointing to it